# How to connect to other process using IPCEventBus

Tags: java, android, ipc

I am sending an object called event inside my application but to another process.

I am using [IPC EventBus](https://github.com/IpcEventBus/ipceventbus). When I register I cannot receive events back.

This  is what I am doing:

```
public class UserActivity extends Activity 
    implements IIpcEventBusConnectionListener, IIpcEventBusObserver {

    @Override
    public void onConnected(IIpcEventBusConnector connector) {
        connector.registerObserver(this);
    }

    ...
}
```

How can I receive the events?

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling `conn.startConnection();`? If you don't then it will not work.

```
IIpcEventBusConnector conn =
        ConnectorFactory.getInstance().buildConnector(context, this, "com.myapp");

conn.startConnection();
```